# Animation delay child elents when close css 3d element

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transitions

I am making menu what must look like book what opening on :hover.

Problem is in delay animation child elements on opening and closing animation.

http://codepen.io/Fillosof/pen/DGwfC

CSS code:

```
#menu ul ul {
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform: rotateX(-90deg); 
transform-origin: top;}

#menu ul li{
perspective: 1000px;}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
height:180px;
transform: rotateX(-25deg);}
```

HTML code

```
<div id="menu">
<ul >
<li><a href="">level 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="">level 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">level 2</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body:

```
<div id="menu">MENU</div>
<div id="flap"></div>
```

then, in the HEAD of your file, type the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#menu").hover(
function() {


  $("#flap").animate({
    height: '+=200'
    }, '0'
);
},

function() {


  $("#flap").animate({
    height: '-=200',
    }, '0'
  );
}
);

});
</script>
```

This is the CSS is as follows:

```
#menu {
width:100%;
position:relative;
height:75px;
background-color:black;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:16pt;
text-align:center;
color:white;
line-height:75px;
}

#flap {
width:100%;
position:relative;
background-color:red;
height:0px;

}
```

Let me know if it worked out! In the #flap you can make the menu which you want to flap out.